# Can I Autowire a Bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand Spring/Spring-boot. My question is, can I use a Bean instantiated/declaired by @Bean to a @Autowired field? Below is my classes, what i have defined.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTestApplication {    
   @Bean(name = "TestServiceInterfaceImplBean")
   TestServiceInterface getTestService() {
      return new TestServiceInterfaceImpl();
   }

   @Autowired
   public ServiceCaller serviceCaller;

   public static void main(String[] args) {     
      ApplicationContext appContext = new 
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBootTestApplication.class);
      Arrays.asList(appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()).forEach(beanName -> 
      System.out.println(beanName));
      SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTestApplication.class, args);
   }
}


@Component()
public class ServiceCaller {    
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier(value = "TestServiceInterfaceImplBean")
   TestServiceInterface testService;

   public ServiceCaller(){
       System.out.println("############################### ServiceCaller");
   }
}

//Service Interface
public interface TestServiceInterface {}

//Interface Implementation Class
public class TestServiceInterfaceImpl implements TestServiceInterface {
  public TestServiceInterfaceImpl() {
      System.out.println("############################### TestServiceInterfaceImpl");
  }
}
```

I know by tagging @Service/@Component to TestServiceInterfaceImpl and removing @Bean and the method getTestService(), i can have @Autowire successful but i am just tyring to understand whether i can Autowire a Bean?

In this case i am getting below exception. By looking at the exception i am not able to understand where and how the loop is created.

**Exception:**

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  springBootTestApplication (field public com.SpringBootTestApplication.service.ServiceCaller com.SpringBootTestApplication.SpringBootTestApplication.serviceCaller)
↑     ↓
|  serviceCaller (field com.SpringBootTestApplication.service.TestServiceInterface com.SpringBootTestApplication.service.ServiceCaller.testService)
└─────┘

Action:

Relying upon circular references is discouraged and they are prohibited by default. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle between beans. As a last resort, it may be possible to break the cycle automatically by setting spring.main.allow-circular-references to true.

Comment: The problem is, as your error indicates, you have a circular dependency. The `@SpringBootApplication` class is an `@Configuration` and has an `@Autowired` `ServiceCaller`, the `ServiceCaller` needs the `TestServiceInterface` which is created by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class, which needs the `ServiceCaller`. So Spring cannot construct one without the other. The problem is not that you aren't able to use `@Bean` the problem is your configuration setup you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better move below part to a Configuration (@Configuration) class:

```
   @Bean(name = "TestServiceInterfaceImplBean")
   TestServiceInterface getTestService() {
      return new TestServiceInterfaceImpl();
   }

   @Autowired
   public ServiceCaller serviceCaller;
```

then do the test again.  And another point,  for ServiceCaller,  you can even define its order after the Bean of TestServiceInterfaceImplBean created.

the 2 configuration class like:

```
    @Configuration
    @AutoConfigureAfter({ MyConfiguration2.class })
    public class MyConfiguration {

    public MyConfiguration() {
    }

    @Autowired
    public ServiceCaller serviceCaller;

}

@Configuration

public class MyConfiguration2 {

    public MyConfiguration2() {
    }

    @Bean(name = "TestServiceInterfaceImplBean")
    public TestServiceInterface getTestService() {
        return new TestServiceInterfaceImpl();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html
The link says SpringBootApplication already do Configuration. My Bean is already inside configuration class. I tried your suggession but that did not worked.

Comment: Just updated the configuration class.  You need remove the `ApplicationContext appContext = new 
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringBootTestApplication.class);
      Arrays.asList(appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()).forEach(beanName -> 
      System.out.println(beanName));` part to check first.